# Raspberry Pi python script not turning off LED

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

(first post)
I just set up a raspberry pi 3 with the monitor view on my laptop over the wifi connection.

I set up two LED lights and one button switch on a breadboard.

I am able to turn the blinking lights on but can not turn the sequence off with the same button.

I have a feeling I am not properly ending my while loop.   Still learning so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT, initial=0) # Blue LED
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT, initial=0) # Orange LED
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN) # Button switch

onoff = 0

try:
    while onoff ==1:
        if onoff==1:
            GPIO.output(25, 1)
            GPIO.output(17, 0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.output(25, 0)
            GPIO.output(17, 1)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        if GPIO.input(7)==1:
            if onoff==0:
                onoff = 1
            else:
                onoff = 0

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: You set onoff to 0 and then check onoff against 1 for the while loop. It'll never enter that

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an event as shown [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO/0.5.1a) or [here](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-2).

Basically an event is something that interrupts normal operation. In this case I'm assuming your `onoff` variable code is meant to act as an "on-off" switch to determine whether or not to execute that one portion of the code with outputs.

A solution would be to infinitely loop over the code you want to execute but only execute it if `onoff` is 1 (True). Any time the button in 7 is pressed, your code will be "interrupted" and another function will be called, switching `onoff` to the opposite state. Your code might then look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT, initial=0) # Blue LED
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT, initial=0) # Orange LED
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN) # Button switch

onoff = 0

def on_off_switch(channel):
    # Flip between 0 (False) and 1 (True)
    onoff = not onoff

# This "event" calls on_off_switch whenever it detects a rising edge on 7
GPIO.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.RISING, callback=on_off_switch)

try:
    # Infinite loop
    while True:
        # Only do stuff if onoff is 1 (True)
        if (onoff):
            GPIO.output(25, 1)
            GPIO.output(17, 0)
            time.sleep(0.2)
            GPIO.output(25, 0)
            GPIO.output(17, 1)
            time.sleep(0.2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop only runs while `onoff == 1`.  The first time you press the button, it gets set to `0`, so the loop exits and there are no further checks for button input.    You want your loop to be infinite (i.e. `while True:` ) and hence breakable only by the `KeyBoardInterrupt`.

Comment: I would like the button to turn off the LEDs as well as the the keyboard.